# dovecot: auth with more then one method posible

Tags: dovecot

is it possible to auth with more then one method with dovecot ?

Ex: password and mysql .... ?

the idea is that I like to have system users and virtual users from a database, and dovecot auth and dovecot deliver to manage this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
You can use multiple databases, so if the password doesn't match in the first database,  
Dovecot checks the next one. This can be useful if you want to easily support having both 
virtual users and also local system users (see Authentication/MultipleDatabases).
```

[Dovecot Wiki link 1](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase)

[Dovecot Wiki link 2](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/MultipleDatabases)